# Laravel chaining "wherenotin" with "like" operator in "orWhere"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to get a list of users that doesn't exist in `allParticipants` array but their name, email or username matches with the `input`. Below is what I've tried

```
User::where('username', $input)
                    ->orWhere('email', $input)
                    ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $input . '%')
                    ->whereNotIn('id', $allParticipants)->get()->toJson()->get();
```

However the above is returning a list of users whose name matches with the input disregarding if they exist in `allParticipants` array or not. What's the correct way to write this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your query:

You are telling Laravel to get *[A]* the list of users that aren't in a specific group of participants **OR** *[B]* the ones that have a specific `email` **OR** *[C]* the ones that have a specific `name`.. so that translates in this:

```php
[A] OR [B] OR [C]
```

That's why when Laravel finds a `user` email that matches with the one provided, it will return it regardless of if is in that specific group (`$appParticipants`) or not.

#### Solution

To have your desired behavior you should do this instead:

```php
User::where('username', $input)
    ->whereNotIn('id', $allParticipants)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($input) {
        $query
            ->where('email', $input)
            ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $input . '%');
    })
    ->get()
    ->toJson()
    ->get();
```

This does the following:

*[A]* Check for the users with ids not in the `$allParticipants` array **AND** follows the next rule: *[B]* have an specific `email` or *[C]* an specific `name`.

```php
[A] AND ([B] OR [C])
```

Comment: @MahadiHasan glad to help. Check the updated answer to understand the difference.